# Sharedpreferences Android listener

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have lookd around but i just don't seem to understand on how to implement a sharedpreference listener. My code is:

```
public class MusicPlayer extends Activity implements OnCompletionListener {
    public static SharedPreferences settings;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
     AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity.settings = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    .....
}

public void onPreferenceChangeListener(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
       //Do something here

}
```

what i am trying to do is somewhere else if something is triggered the sharedpreference key stays the same but the value changes and i need this value
For some reason my listener never actually calls. i have tried some other ways but i think i might be doing it wrong. any suggestions on how i can get a listener to work or does anyone know what the problem is?

any help would be great

thanks

ps. im not extending PreferenceActivity that should cause a problem right? i tried that but my program then just crashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you want a listener for your Sharedpreferences settings. This can be done by creating a listener like

```
listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
 public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
   public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(
        SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {

        System.out.println(key);
 }
};
settings.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
```

Comment: would this be inside my onCreate or outside of it?

Comment: while im making the listener it gives me an error and says i have to create a local variable or something else with it. when i do i cant make it equal to "new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() "

did you also mean to put two onSharedPreferenceChanged inside the listener? or was that by accedent

Comment: never mind fixed the listener just wondering about the "onSharedPreferenceChanged" tho

Comment: just wondering is it possible to convert the prefs as a string if i wanted to compare it to a string would it be possible?

Comment: Yes by prefs.getString(key,defValue)